# Issues loading multiple Htmls in two webview, flickering?

Tags: android, html, webview, transition, assets

As I am having an application with 135 screens.I know it will be a stupid plan for an application but unfortunately this is the requirement.As we are planning to make all the screens as html then putting it in assets then reading it to a string and loading it in two webviews. It should load with animations.So we are using 2 webviews.

I dont know how much efficient this method will be.As I read in most of the blogs and forums.This will make a lot of performance issues.Now my problem is that I am trying to load 4 html's in 2 webviews correspondingly and applying the animations to the webview. This 2 webview will be in a frame layout.When I do the same I am getting many problems listed below.

1. Webview is flickering.
2. When the animation happens sometimes unloaded html's are shown in between which is been previously loaded.
3. Sometimes the page is not loading it will only show if any user interaction happen on the screen.
4. Some times a white page is shown in between loading two pages.

Flickering and white page between are the main problems am facing.Can any one let me know how we can solve these issues.I am really struggling to get this done.If this is not the efficient approach to load 135 html's let me know the best one.Some piece of code is mentioned below just to show how am tackling this....Thanksss in advance..

```
wv1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
                        readFromAssests("rechercherunjob.html"), "text/html",
                        "UTF-8", null);

                anim_right_to_left_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left_in);
                anim_left_to_right_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left_out);

                anim_left_to_right_out.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                                wv1.bringToFront();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoadHTMLActivity.this,
                                                "anim end 2",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                                wv2.loadDataWithBaseURL(
                                        "file:///android_asset/",
                                        readFromAssests("blank.html"),
                                        "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                            }
                        });


                final Handler Handler1 = new Handler();
                Runnable mUpdateTimeTask1 = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        wv1.setAnimation(anim_right_to_left_in);
                        wv2.setAnimation(anim_left_to_right_out);
                    }
                };
                Handler1.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask1, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it will be better to use `Fragments` and set custom animation transition for them and do not use several `WebViews`. Your application will never will work fine if you will try to keep in memory absolutely all 125 htmls.

Comment: Now you are using `Fragments` instead of `WebViews`?